# Root site in sharepoin online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can I save a site template for the sharepoint online root site

It's by default created with modern experience

Is it mean I can only save template for subsite not the root

Answer (score 0):

The feature save site as template only supports classic sites in SharePoint Online.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/save-download-and-upload-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template

Per my knowledge, the option you have is to use [site swap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/url-that-resides-under-root-site-collection-is-broken) to replace the root site with either a modern communication site or a classic team site. For a classic team site, you can save it as template.